# Activity crashing while JsonParsing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, currency

i'm trying to make an app on unit converter.
all the other implementations i have done but i'm not able to fetch real time values for currency.
I found a way of "JSON parsing". I searched for it and created this code.

```
package com.example.unitconverter;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HttpExample extends Activity{

Spinner S1,S2;
TextView tv;
EditText et;
Button abutton;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;

static final String URL = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.currency);

    S1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    S2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
    abutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    abutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new Read().execute("rate");

        }
    });


}

public JSONObject retrieve(String from,String to) throws ClientProtocolException,IOException,JSONException{

    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(from + "&to=" + to);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);

    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(status == 200){
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);

        return last;

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(HttpExample.this, "error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;

    }

}
public class Read extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{

     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
        }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {


            json = retrieve(S1.getSelectedItem().toString(),S2.getSelectedItem().toString());

            return json.getString(params[0]);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(HttpExample.this, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Double F=Double.parseDouble(result);
        Double D = Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString());
        String newstring = Double.toString(D*F);

        tv.setText(newstring);

    }
}
```

}

the xml file contains 2 Spinners containing currency abbreviations, 1 EditText, 1 TextView and 1 Button"Convert".
When i click on "Convert", i get a message that "Unfortunately, UnitConverter stopped working".

I'm new to android and hence don't know much about errors but the much i could understand from the LogCat is that there is some problem in doInBackground() function.

Please help as my last date for submission of this app is very near.

thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at     java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:244)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at     java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at com.example.unitconverter.HttpExample$Read.onPostExecute(HttpExample.java:119)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at com.example.unitconverter.HttpExample$Read.onPostExecute(HttpExample.java:1)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-12 16:26:36.494: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

UPDATE:

I got my error..I was using JSONArray instead of JSONObject.

```
public JSONObject retrieve(String from,String to) throws    ClientProtocolException,IOException,JSONException{

    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(from + "&to=" + to);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);

    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(status == 200){
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONObject last = new JSONObject(data);     
        return last;

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(Currency.this, "Error!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;

    }
```

Thanks Everybody

Comment: @jimpanzer- i have added the logcat

Answer (score 3):

Remove this

```
 Toast.makeText(HttpExample.this, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

inside of `doInBackgrond`.

As `doInBackground` doesn't run in UI thread, you are not allowed perform UI operation there.

So place Toast in onPostExecute or in `runonUiThred`

Comment: Yes, you can not perform UI tasks in doInBackground, +1 for answer

Comment: @AkshaySethi You are returning `null` in doInBackground and you are trying to perform operation on `null` value, you'll get `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Pragnani- i'm returning null if exception has occurred. but normally i'm returning the string

Comment: @AkshaySethi Thats I have a double regarding your json value, it may be returning null...I think you are getting another Exception or error please update your logcat in the question

Comment: @Pragnani-what should i return instead of null?

Comment: @AkshaySethi Return any other value like empty string or Best will be Checking Whether your `json` is `null` or not in the `onPostExecute` and if it not then perform operation on it

Comment: @Pragnani- i have removed null and made it "0". but now its showing 0.0 in the textview.

Comment: @AkshaySethi Yes it will show value based on the returned value